# UITableViewSeparator in a grouped tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In IB,

Style: Grouped, Single Line Etched, color white.
The background of my view is clear color.

In viewDidLoad of this ViewController, I create a dummy background view:

```
UIView *tableBgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
tableBgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tableBgView;
[tableBgView release];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath I have:

```
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView = bgView;
    [bgView release];
```

What I am trying to do is have a rectangle background instead of the rounded rectangle look for a grouped table and because in my cellForRowAtIndexPath I create a clearColor backgroundView to get rid of the rounded rect look, I do not have a separator anymore.  Do I just add another single pixel UIView line that is at the bottom of this bgView to get my separator back?  Or is there a better way?  Thanks.

Comment: the best way is to subclass UITableViewCell and draw your own borders. I did it, and I will provide an example later (I'm on a mobile device right now).

Comment: I did subclass UITableViewCell as well.  But when I threw it in a grouped tableView, It gave me rounded corners.  That's why I added the bgView to the cell.  If you mean add a UIView of 1px at the bottom of my UITableViewCell subclass, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this is my `drawRect:`, this will remove the rounded cells. This is also used in a grouped table view controller as you see.

Here is a sample image:

[image: sample image]

`- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

```
// A left and right margin
float margin = 10.0f;

// Copy the rect and modify it's values to match the margin
CGRect _rect = rect;
_rect.size.width = _rect.size.width - (margin * 2);
_rect.origin.x = margin;

// Fill with a background color, in this case, white.
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(context, _rect);

// Set a line color
[[UIColor grayColor] set];

// Shift the move point to match our margin
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, margin, _rect.size.height);

// Draw the line with the same width as the cell PLUS the margin (because we shifted it).
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _rect.size.width + margin, _rect.size.height);

// Finish
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

}